# access to mounted luks partition by non-root user

Tags: encryption, luks, privilege-escalation, dm-crypt

Recently I searched substitute for truecrypt and played a bit with cryptsetup. The steps I did:

1. `mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sdb1`
2. `sudo cryptsetup open --type luks /dev/sdb1 enc_vol`
3. `sudo mount /dev/mapper/enc_vol /mnt`

After that I (non-root user) can chdir to `/mnt` and can see files but can't write anything there. Only root can write, but that is very inconvenient for me. As `ls -l /dev/mapper/enc_vol` shows it is symlink owned by root and which points to `/dev/dm-1`.

Commands like `chown "username":"username"` and `chmod 777` cannot change "root"ness of the beforementioned symlink to `/dev/dm-1`.

My question: how can I mount LUKS partitions encrypted by cryptsetup to be able to write files in it being non-root user?

Answer (score 8):

**TLDR:** Mount the filesystem in the user's home directory.

This is not specific to luks since it applies to mounting in general. I have not tested with ext4 but I don't see a reason why it will be different from ext3 (which I have tested).

```
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb1 enc_vol
mkdir ~/enc_vol_mnt
sudo mount /dev/mapper/enc_vol ~/enc_vol_mnt
```

The regular user should now be able to read, write and delete files and directories in ~/enc_vol_mnt.

There are some other solutions to this problem on [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/196653/how-do-i-manually-mount-a-linux-file-system-read-write-as-a-normal-user#196684).

As a side note, you can also use the `-o users,rw,umask=0000` mount options when the file system being mounted is FAT or NTFS. The mount man page has more info on this.

Answer (score 7):

For future readers:

Freshly formatted filesystem's root has usually rights of *rwxr-xr-x* and indeed is writable by root only.

On the first mount, depending on the future use of this partition - either **chown** the root of the mounted drive (**not** the device in */dev* !) to user intended to use it exclusively or **chmod** it to *rwxrwxrwxt* to have it system-wide accessible, in a matter similar to */tmp*. Or use any user rights/owner combination in-between (for example writable to members of the specific group, etc).

The setting is persistent across reboots/remounts.

TL;DR:

```
mount /dev/DEVICE /SOMEWHERE
chown USER:GROUP /SOMEWHERE
```

or

```
mount /dev/DEVICE /SOMEWHERE
chmod a+rwxt /SOMEWHERE
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few things to try on your particular system.

You can look at udisksctl per [this mailing list article](http://www.saout.de/pipermail/dm-crypt/2014-February/003939.html)

> Assuming you have udisks2, this shouldn't be a problem:
>
> $ udisksctl
>   Usage:
>     udisksctl [OPTION...] COMMAND
>
> Commands:
>
> help            Shows this information
>
> info            Shows information about an object
>
> dump            Shows information about all objects
>
> status          Shows high-level status
>
> monitor         Monitor changes to objects
>
> mount           Mount a filesystem
>
> unmount         Unmount a filesystem
>
> unlock          Unlock an encrypted device
>
> lock            Lock an encrypted device
>
> loop-setup      Set-up a loop device
>
> loop-delete     Delete a loop device
>
> power-off       Safely power off a drive
>
> smart-simulate  Set SMART data for a drive
>
> Use "udisksctl COMMAND --help" to get help on each command.
>
> The 'unlock' command seems useful to you.

Alternately, as root, set up fstab correctly, perhaps starting by reading this [Superuser answer to Linux - Mount device with specific user rights](https://superuser.com/a/320640/403289)

> To mount a device with certain rights, you can use the -o Option directive while mounting the device. To mount the device you described, run:
>
> mount -t deviceFileFormat -o umask=filePermissons,gid=ownerGroupID,uid=ownerID /device /mountpoint

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am learning so I want to do such things without using external tools.  Also I found that ext4 cannot be mounter by gid,uid in answer http://superuser.com/a/320640 "For filesystems that does not support mounting as a specific user (like ext4) the above will give the error

Unrecognized mount option "uid=33" or missing value
" Still needs root to write. Lubuntu 15.10 64. When I plug my usb pop us window where I can enter password for luks and then use, write in usb. But in command line I cannot write ( It is really annoying.

Comment: For anyone interested, there's a good write-up [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/329639/6860) about using `udisksctl` for unlocking/mounting, and for unmounting/locking/powering-down.